# How to apply several Label filters on the same column?

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I have to apply 2 label filters on the same colum of my Pivot Table. Label filters are

```
Does Not Begin With REF????
Not Not End With REF????
```

However, when I select the second one, the first one is removed.

It is not possible to apply several Label filtrers on the same column? Do you know some workaround?

Thank you

Comment: No, you can't use two label filters. The simplest option would be adding a column to your data source to flag the ones you don't want.

Comment: Ok so I will add a column thank you.